# Dectect runtime if UWP app is downloaded from package flight group

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp

When publishing a UWP application to the store you can choose to distribute your app to only members of a Package flight.

I would like to detect runtime if the app has been downloaded from such a test flight group.

I want to do this because I want to use a different api url for this test group. and once I'm ready to release the app I would like to use a different url.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-flights) you can use different packages for each flight group. So I would just embed the URL you want into the package that you're deploying

> When you set up package flights, you can choose the specific people
>   who should get specific packages by adding them a flight group. **Anyone
>   in a flight group who is using a device running a version of Windows
>   10 that supports package flights (Windows.Desktop build 10586 or
>   later; Windows.Mobile build 10586.63 or later) will get packages from
>   the package flight(s) that you designate for that particular group.**
>   Anyone who has not been added to one of your flight groups, or is
>   using a device that doesn’t support package flights, will get packages
>   from the non-flighted submission.

Comment: You're not understand the concept of package flight. By using package flight, developer can deploy the package to test group A, then, deploy the same one to the public. "just embed the URL" does not make sense.

Comment: @pnp0a03 they CAN deploy it to the public but they don't have too. You don't have to do it that way. You can use it for testing.

Comment: I understand why you want this.
Normally you want to generate 1 build which can be published on both package flight and release to public.
Now, you have to build 2 separate builds with own "connection strings" which will cost you also valuable build time on your server due the native compilation required.
I tried to use A/B testing for it, but it has the same issue. You don't know which package you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Today is solved this same problem by a rather different approach.

Instead of relying on the flight or a/b test, i took matters in own hand.

To be clear; i have 3 different "connection strings": debug (local machine), preview (for testers) and release (production).

Debug is only used on the development machine. On my build server, i created one build for the release configuration. This way both testers and end-users using the same build as should be.

In my application i added the [Uri activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).  This way, you can start your application with just something like "HelloWorldApp://".

On the desktop of testers i have created a shortcut calling "HelloWorldApp://test". This is the only manual step you have to take on the testers side. Opening this link opens your application but with the extra argument to check on and overwrite the default "release" connection strings.

This has 2 advantages. You testers can still get hold on the test package as package flight and use it separately from the production users, but also this package can directly be submitted to the release group without change or separate build. Also when using the default shortcut, you're using the production version. Means switching environments without reinstalling.

Hope it solves your issue too, but for now it's likely the only possible way to do this.